# IMAP $Phishing and $NotPhishing flags in Gmail -- how to use them?

Tags: gmail, imap

When using IMAP in Gmail, after `SELECT`ing a folder (like `INBOX`), you see an output line like this:

```
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $NotPhishing $Phishing)
```

My initial guess was that `$Phishing` corresponds to messages that say

> **Be careful with this message.**
>   It contains a suspicious link that was used to steal people's personal information. Unless you trust the sender, don't click links or reply with personal information.

in the web interface, which is what I was trying to find, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Moreover, I have no idea which messages even have the flags that start with `$`.

How are those flags beginning with `$` used?

Comment: $ is often used for custom/non-standard flags.

Comment: @Max: Right. My question is *how* one would use these non-standard flags.